# How to get elements out from list of lists when having the same position

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists where I want to extract the element from each list at same position. How do I do so? As an example. I have like:

> L = [[A,B,C,D][B,C,D,E][C,D,E,F]]

Now I want all the letters from position 0 which would give me:

> A, B, C - > L[0][0], L[1][0], L[2][0]

I tried to use:

```
[row[0] for row in L]
```

and

```
L[:-1][0]
```

But none of them works for me.

Comment: I'm confused. Why is `D` in the output when it's never first in any of the sub-lists?

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped. It should only be A,B,C.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening to you is because of the way you made your list.

```
[[A,B,C,D][B,C,D,E][C,D,E,F]]
```

You have to separate the list (i.e you forgot the commas in between each list). Change your list to something like this

```
[[A,B,C,D],[B,C,D,E],[C,D,E,F]]
```

Also, when testing this it doesn't work as its not in quotation marks, but i'm guessing there's a reason for that.

Hope I could help :3

Comment: Haha, this is totally it. When I worked on this example I made that fix with out thinking about it. Only now, after reading your solution do I remember doing that lol!! ITS USUALLY the simple things.

Comment: ah no problem! Make sure to select this as answer to help the next person with the same problem :3

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Try this,

```
[v[0] for i, v in enumerate(L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, 
I don't understand why its not work for you:

```
[row[0] for row in L]
```

output:

```
['A','B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your list with `zip`.

```
>>> L = [['A','B','C','D'],['B','C','D','E'],['C','D','E','F']]
>>> t = zip(*L) # list(*zip(L)) in Python 3
```

`t[position]` will give you all the elements for a specific position.

```
>>> t[0]
('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> t[1]
('B', 'C', 'D')
>>> t[2]
('C', 'D', 'E')
>>> t[3]
('D', 'E', 'F')
```

By the way, your attempted solution should have worked.

```
>>> [row[0] for row in L] 
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

If you only care about one specific index, this is perfectly fine. If you want the information for all indices, transposing the whole list of lists with `zip` is the way to go.